# Backbone-Form.js - replacing Radio editor template

Tags: forms, backbone.js

New to using Backbone-form.js.  I was wondering how to replace the Radio editor default template using a template option in the schema as follows ...

```
var altFieldTemplate = _.template('\
        <ul>\
        <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>\
        <li>\
        <input type="radio" name="<%= item.name %>" value="<%= item.value %>" id="<%= item.id %>" />\
        <label for="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.label %></label>\
        </li>\
        <% }); %>\
        </ul>\
        ', null, Backbone.Form.templateSettings);

schema: {
        keyYesNo: { type: 'Radio', title: ' ', editorClass: 'radio-field', options: [{val: 'y', label: 'yes'}, {val: 'n', label: 'no'}],
            template: altFieldTemplate},
        },
```

In my example I am using the default template for the Radio editor just to see if I can get it to display the Radio buttons without an error.  Unfortunately I get the following error ..  "ReferenceError: items is not defined".